# When to use RequireComponent vs AddComponent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a visual detector that uses a mesh to figure if something is in the vision of the detector.  The requirements naturally include a mesh collider, which needs a mesh to be populated.  In  my code I'm currently requiring the mesh collider component (in addition to a mesh filter, so I can rotate as needed), and then manually configuring isTrigger and convex properties respectively.

Now here's my question... what is the cleaner solution?  Should I be manually instantiating a mesh collider OnEnable with the proper configuration, or continue using RequireComponent?

I'm using RequireComponent and I'm wondering if that's the proper direction to take.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally that's a little bit opinion based.

However, for clarification: [`RequireComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html) is a pure Inspector Attribute, meaning it only has effect if the component is actually added via the drag&drop or the `Add Component` button in the Inspector, it will have no effect (and thus your code might fail) if

- the component is added on runtime via `AddComponent`
- the Attribute is added after the component already was added

How exactly you want to do this is up to you and your users. Many people (and also SDKs like e.g. MRTK) for this reason introduced the extension `EnsureComponent` which looks somewhat like

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T EnsureComponent<T>(this Component component) where T : Component
    {
        return EnsureComponent<T>(component.gameObject);
    }

    public static T EnsureComponent<T>(this GameObject gameObject) where T : Component
    {
        if(gameObject.TryGetComponent(out T component))
        {
            return component;
        }

        return gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
    }
}
```

and then initialize via

```
[SerializeField] private MeshFilter meshFilter;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!meshFilter)
    {
        meshFilter = this.EnsureComponent<MeshFilter>();
    }
}
```

you can even stimulate the behavior of `RequireComponent` as well and do something like e.g.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        var previous = meshFilter;
        if(!meshFilter) meshFilter = this.EnsureComponent<MeshFilter>();
        if(meahFilter != previous) UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
    }
#endif
```

---

Now to my personal opinion:

Have in mind though that for most components the user has to configure stuff anyway! For instance a runtime added `MeshFilter` is worth nothing if you do not also assign a `Mesh` to it.

=> imho for most cases it is *better* UX to rather expose the field to the Inspector

```
[SerializeField] private MeshFilter meshFilter;
```

which is enough hint for the user that there should be a `MeshFilter` and then

- as a fallback only use `GetComponent`
- otherwise throw an exception right away in `Awake` so the user can add missing components

like e.g.

```
private void Awake()
{
    if(!meshFilter) meshFilter = Getcomponent<MeshFilter>();

    if(!meshFilter) throw new MissingReferenceException($"{nameof(meshFilter)} is not assigned!");
}
```

This is quite explicit, and you could also just rely on the exception anyway being thrown as soon as you try to access the un-assigned `meshFilter`, but I prefer to already get them right away when the app starts and not eventually at some point in the app lifecycle later on - or maybe never if condition is never met.

I personally am spare with `RequireComponent`  as it slightly reduces flexibility and limits your component in a way that the referenced components definitely need to be on the same `GameObject`.